# how to put int in HashMap jni?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have such method

```
jobject Profiling::getFullStatistic(JNIEnv *env)
{
    env->PushLocalFrame(256); // fix for local references

    jclass mapClass = env->FindClass("java/util/HashMap");

    if (mapClass == nullptr)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    jmethodID init = env->GetMethodID(mapClass, "<init>", "(I)V");
    jobject hashMap = env->NewObject(mapClass, init, m_values.size());
    jmethodID put = env->GetMethodID(mapClass, "put", "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");

    for (auto &it: m_values)
    {
        env->CallObjectMethod(hashMap, put, env->NewStringUTF(it.first.c_str()), env->NewStringUTF(std::to_string(it.second).c_str()));
    }

    return env->PopLocalFrame(hashMap);
}
```

At the end I get `Map<String, String>` , now I would like to change this Map type to `Map<String, Integer>`

So, I just changed a signature of `put` method to this

```
jmethodID put = env->GetMethodID(mapClass, "put", "(Ljava/lang/Object;I;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
```

As far as I know `int` signature is `I` ...

And also I changed this line

```
env->CallObjectMethod(hashMap, put, env->NewStringUTF(it.first.c_str()), it.second);
```

But know I got such error

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewStringUTF called with pending 
exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method 
"Ljava/util/HashMap;.put(Ljava/lang/Object;I;)Ljava/lang/Object;"
at java.util.Map com..ar.JniInterface.getProfilingStatistic(long) 
(JniInterface.java:-2)
at void com..ar.ui.fragments.ar.ArScreen.lambda$testDeleteIt$1$ArScreen() 
(ArScreen.java:156)
at void 
com..ar.ui.fragments.ar.-$$Lambda$ArScreen$zqdXNYFzVzmF_ZYFKJRM26bZzUw.run() 
(lambda:-1)
at void android.os.Handler.handleCallback(android.os.Message) 
(Handler.java:873)
at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) 
(Handler.java:99)
at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:214)
at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) 
(ActivityThread.java:6990)
at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, 
java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() 
(RuntimeInit.java:493)
 at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) 
(ZygoteInit.java:1445)

 in call to NewStringUTF
 from java.util.Map com..ar.JniInterface.getProfilingStatistic(long)
 "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
 | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x76dbefb8 self=0x759e614c00
 | sysTid=18571 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x76251b3560
 | state=R schedstat=( 1106979853 124044847 973 ) utm=95 stm=15 core=4 HZ=100
 | stack=0x7fc9911000-0x7fc9913000 stackSize=8MB
 | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
```

**EDIT**

If I try to pass int as Integer (as @Botje mantioned)

jobject Profiling::getFullStatistic(JNIEnv *env)
    {
        env->PushLocalFrame(256); // fix for local references

```
    jclass mapClass = env->FindClass("java/util/HashMap");

    if (mapClass == nullptr)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    jmethodID init = env->GetMethodID(mapClass, "<init>", "(I)V");
    jobject hashMap = env->NewObject(mapClass, init, m_values.size());
    jmethodID put = env->GetMethodID(mapClass, "put", "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");

    jclass j_Integer = env->FindClass("java/lang/Integer");
    jmethodID j_Integer_valueOf = env->GetMethodID(j_Integer, "valueOf", "(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;");

    for (auto &it: m_values)
    {
        jobject j_intValue = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(j_Integer, j_Integer_valueOf, it.second);
        env->CallObjectMethod(hashMap, put, env->NewStringUTF(it.first.c_str()), j_intValue);
    }

    return env->PopLocalFrame(hashMap);
}
```

I get such error

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallStaticObjectMethodV called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Ljava/lang/Integer;.valueOf(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;"

Comment: I'm not sure how generic works (if works at all) at JNI level, but why not to try to use `Integer` class instead of `int`?

Comment: As @sklott mentioned, the value-type of your `HashMap` is `Integer`, not `int`. There's no autoboxing of Java types in C++, so you'll have to construct `Integer` instances yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `Integer#valueOf(int)` from C++ and pass the result to `HashMap#put(Object, Object)`:

```cpp
jclass j_Integer = env->FindClass("java/lang/Integer");
jmethodID j_Integer_valueOf = env->GetStaticMethodID(j_Integer, "valueOf", "(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;");
jmethodID put = env->GetMethodID(mapClass, "put", "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");

for (auto &it: m_values) {
    jobject j_intValue = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(j_Integer, j_Integer_valueOf, it.second);
    env->CallObjectMethod(hashMap, put, env->NewStringUTF(it.first.c_str()), j_intValue);
}
```

Comment: Depending on how many entries there are in `m_values`, it may be required to delete the local reference to `j_intValue` at the end of each iteration to avoid filling up the local reference table.

Comment: *and* the reference to the key, yes. I presumed OP was aware of it (using Push/PopLocalFrame) and pre-allocated enough room for local refs, as the original code already creates two objects per value in `m_values`.

Comment: Doh. You need to use `GetStaticMethodID`. Edited.

Comment: Alternatively, you can go with `NewObject`: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipeNo047